# high resolution timer freezing the rest of my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

we have an app (which involve cocos2d) that works great.
in on of my classes i had to implement a high resolution timer of about 1ms or less.

the timer class is working, but because i have a while(1), **the rest of the app is not even loaded and the screen is black -it deals with my while(1) only**

here is my code :

```
-(void)HighResolutionTimer
{


    while(1)
    {
        if(TimerFlag==0) //take time once
        {
             start = [NSDate date];
            TimerFlag=1;            
        }


        end= [NSDate date]; //check timer


        if([end timeIntervalSinceDate:start]*1000.0f >0.5) //wait for 1ms
        {
            TimerFlag=0;
            [self sampleAudio]; //do my job(with NSLog)
        }

        if(stopTimer==1) //break
        {stopTimer=0; break;}

    }


}
```

what can i input to this while(1) in order to **let processor do other stuff in parallel** ?
does this method is too heavy for the iphone processor ?
there is another way to get call each 1ms to something ?

Answer (score 0):

> what can i input to this while(1) in order to let processor do other
>   stuff in parallel ?

You can put this code into another thread using GCD

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^ {
   [self HighResolutionTimer];
});
```

> does this method is too heavy for the iphone processor ?

It is of course, it's basically infinite loop.

> there is another way to get call each 1ms to something ?

Have you tried using `NSTimer`? Try

```
NSTimer *timer =   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(HighResolutionTimer)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES];
```

Comment: i am not that stupid. if you will read again , i CANT use the NSTimer because it is not go under the resolution of 50ms. i need 1ms or less! SO i have to do it in another way. i couldnt understand the dispatch command you just wrote.

Comment: how do i put that in another thread? or where in my code i have to put that line ?  i couldn't understand this threads thing.

Comment: Read the GCD reference for fundamentals of using background threading via GCD, of which I wrote, here's a link to the reference. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html